# Storing quiz questions in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, radio-button

I am trying to create a small quiz program in JavaScript. All of the questions are contained in array and each question is an object containing question itself, choices for user to choose and answer. Quiz loop through the all questions array and print the question and the options for user to choose from. I want choices to be radio buttons. I am struggling to figure out how to populate radio buttons with the questions choices text. Any idea how can do this please?

```js
      var userChoices = document.getElementsByTagName('input[type:radio]');
      var questions = 
      [
        {
          question: "What is the capital of United Kingdom?",
          choices: ["Manchester", "Birmingham", "London", "Birmingham"],
          answer: 2
        },
        
        {
          question: "What is the capital of United States?",
          choices: ["California", "New York", "Miami", "Florida"],
          answer: 1
        }
        
        
      ];
      
      for ( var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++ ) {
        var question = questions[i].question;
        document.write ( question );
        var options = questions[i].choices;
        for ( var opt in options ) {
           for ( var radios in userChoices ) {
             userChoices[radios].value = options[opt];
             
           }
        }
        
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <input type="radio" name="choices"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="choices"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="choices"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="choices"><br>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you heard of Angular.js? I think it will help you

Comment: @yossico: Don't you think `Angular` is too big for this?

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle example so i could help you ?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm required to use only pure javascript without any library or framework.

Comment: @knight: Do you want a vanilla JS solution? Would be open to using `jQuery`?

Comment: Create a div for each question and in each div you could add a p-tag with the question text and below you can create another div where you output radio buttons with the value and the text

Comment: I've just started to learn javascript and been advised to stay away from libraries and frameworks until have a solid understanding of javascript itself. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: http://jsbin.com/boduzerade/edit?html,output

Comment: @knight: Let me know if my answer is what you are looking at

Comment: @SandeepNayak: yes this is something I was looking for. In your code lable and input will they have same value?

Comment: Label is just text. and yes the value of radio button would be the choices you have or anything that you can interpret in the code

Comment: @SandeepNayak: how do I go about checking the value of a selected radio button. I tried radioEle.checked === true and it didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your JS code like below:

```js
      var questions = 
      [
        {
          question: "What is the capital of United Kingdom?",
          choices: ["Manchester", "Birmingham", "London", "Birmingham"],
          answer: 2
        },
        
        {
          question: "What is the capital of United States?",
          choices: ["California", "New York", "Miami", "Florida"],
          answer: 1
        }
        
        
      ];
      
      for ( var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++ ) {
        var question = questions[i].question;
        document.write ( question );
        var options = questions[i].choices;
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
         var name = "radio"+i; 
        for ( var opt in options ) {
        
          var radioEle = document.createElement("input");
          radioEle.type = "radio";          
          radioEle.value = options[opt];
          radioEle.name = name;
          document.body.appendChild(radioEle);
          var label = document.createElement("Label");
          label.innerHTML = options[opt];
          document.body.appendChild(label);
          document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
        
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need more explanation I will provide it.

```
<script>

    window.onload = function () {

        var questions =
      [
        {
            question: "What is the capital of United Kingdom?",
            choices: ["Manchester", "Birmingham", "London", "Birmingham"],
            answer: 2
        },

        {
            question: "What is the capital of United States?",
            choices: ["California", "New York", "Miami", "Florida"],
            answer: 1
        }


      ];

        var container = document.getElementById('container');
        for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
            var questionContainer = document.createElement('DIV');
            questionContainer.textContent = questions[i].question;

            var options = questions[i].choices;
            for (var opt in options) {
                //create radiobutton
                //append radiobutton to a div 
            }
            container.appendChild(questionContainer);
        }
    };
 </script>
```

Comment: your solution is pretty much understandable for me. My main problems is when I try to populate the radio buttons for choices like this > radiobutton.value = choices[i]; it doesn't work. can you please how can i add choices text to radio buttons. Thanks

Comment: radio button has a value attribute, but not a text attribute.
You append text next to the radiobutton in to a span or just next.
<input type="radio" name="wathever" value="1"> <span>First Choice</span>

Comment: thats why I 'm using radio.value = options[i]; but its not working for some reason.

Comment: You need a label for radios, bot just text

Comment: Yes, you could use following syntax 
<label for="firstChoiceId">
    <input type="radio" id="firstChoiceId" name="wathever" value="1">
    First Choice
</label>
But he's just starting with developing, that's why I mentioned it like before.